# Expand only one row at a time for React-DataTable component

Tags: reactjs, datatable, react-table

I'm working with React DataTable `react-data-table-component` and I need to have an expandable table. In order to make the table expandable I have set `expandableRows` as true and I have also provided `expandableRowsComponent`. With the default react data-table implementation I can expand all the available rows in the table simultaneously. However, I would like to expand only 1 row at a time. So if I try to expand another row the already expanded row should collapse. How can I achieve this?

I also tried to use `onRowExpandToggled`. When I click a row to expand it returns the row that I expanded and value true. When the row is collapsed it returns false. I believe that I need to use this function to auto collapse the expanded rows but not sure how?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?  I need same solution right now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by leveraging on one more prop, the **expandableRowExpanded** which tracks the current row that is expanded. It takes a callback that you can use to compare to a state that you set in the **onRowExpandToggled** prop.

```
          const [currentRow, setCurrentRow] = useState(null);


          <DataTable
            expandableRows
            expandableRowExpanded={(row) => (row === currentRow)}
            expandOnRowClicked
            onRowClicked={(row) => setCurrentRow(row)}
            expandableRowsComponent={<ExpandableTable />}
            onRowExpandToggled={(bool, row) => setCurrentRow(row)}
            data={filteredData}
         />
```